# Creating a Chat client with JavaFX using sockets

Tags: multithreading, sockets, javafx

I am having trouble coding the socket side of a JavaFX chat client. This is my first time having to deal with socket in any sort of way, so some trouble was expected. I've been following this page to design the server-client side:
http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html

My problem is getting text I enter into the GUI into a DataInputSteam and DataOutputStream so that others on the same server can see the changes. I do 
not understand how to convert the text in the UI to something the sockets
can work with.

Here is part of my controller class:

```
@FXML
private TextArea messageArea;

@FXML
private Button sendButton;

private ChatClient client;

@FXML
public void initialize() {

    client = new ChatClient(ChatServer.HOSTNAME, ChatServer.PORT);

    sendButton.setOnAction(event -> {
        client.handle(messageArea.getText());
    });
}
```

The ChatClient class is a Runnable with a DataInputStream and DataOutputStream field that connects to a Socket. I haven't changed much from the link:

```
public class ChatClient implements Runnable {

private Socket socket;
private Thread thread;
private DataInputStream streamIn;
private DataOutputStream streamOut;
private ChatClientThread client;

public ChatClient(String serverName, int port) {
    System.out.println("Establishing connection...");
    try {
        socket = new Socket(serverName, port);
        System.out.println("Connected: " + socket);
        start();
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
       System.out.println("Unknown host: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unexpected: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (thread != null) {
        try {
            streamOut.writeUTF(streamIn.readUTF());
            streamOut.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Sending error: " + e.getMessage());
            stop();
        }
    }
}

public void handle(String msg) {
    try {
        streamOut.writeUTF(msg);
        streamOut.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not handle message: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(msg);
}

public void start() throws IOException {
    streamIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    streamOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    if (thread == null) {
        client = new ChatClientThread(this, socket);
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

So in the controller class, I am calling the handle method which deals with the streams. The original code just wrote to the console, so I had to change the line:
streamIn = new DataInputStream(System.in) 
to 
streamIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

There is also a ChatClientThread class that extends Thread and just calls ChatClient.handle() in its run method.

I guess my question is how to update a GUI whenever writeUTF and readUTF interact with the DataStreams. I understand that streamOut.writeUTF(msg) changes the DataOutputStream to "have" that string, but I'm not sure how I'm supposed to use that datastream to update my gui so that all clients using the application can see the update. The way I have it now, if I run two instances of the JavaFX app, they dont' communicate through the UI or the console. My program just stalls whenever I click the send button

Comment: The text that is sent from the server comes in the `streamIn`, so you have to append all data you get from that stream into your `messageArea`.

Comment: Any idea on how to do that? In the client class I added a getter for streamIn in my client class, then tried calling messageArea.setText(streamIn.readUTF()) in my controller class, but this causes the JVM to crash.

Comment: You probably need to wrap the call to `messageArea.setText` in [Platform.runLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-).

Comment: You may be interested in alternate approaches using a [websocket server](http://www.hascode.com/2013/08/creating-a-chat-application-using-java-ee-7-websockets-and-glassfish-4/#The_Websocket_Endpoint)  and [websocket client](http://www.hascode.com/2014/11/creating-different-websocket-chat-clients-in-java/).  It is a bit more complicated in approach, but adds some deployment flexibility as it can work through firewalls.  For interoperability with other chat servers you may want to investigate [xmpp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMPP).

Comment: jewelsea, I'll take a look at that, thank you.

Comment: I'm still running into the JVM crashing when I use Platform. For sockets, the way that I'm understanding it is that when the a Client writes to a DataOutputStream, it becomes the DataInputStream for the Server, and then when the Server responds, the server's output stream becomes the Client's input stream. Is that right? In my ClientThread class, the run() method just infinitely loops and calls ChatClient.handle(), because I think that method is where I'm supposed to send the text in a textfield to the server. I'm not sure how to do that, though

Comment: What kind of crashes? Could you update your question with the output of these crashes?

Comment: By crash, I mean the FX application stops responding and I get a Windows messaage telling me that the Java SE Environment isn't responding.